# Getting string from NSManagedObject

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

When I try to get a string value from an NSManagedObject, I get this

```
<Entity: 0x1e043140> (entity: Entity; id: 0x1e041c30 <x-coredata://8F48C331-B879-47B4-B257-4802A13ED12C/Entity/p4> ; data: {
number = "<UITextField: 0x1d8b7cc0; frame = (159 183; 161 30); text = 'test'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1d8b3c10>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1d892a30>> : ";
})
```

how do I get the string from this (it's text = 'test';)

i get the object using this

```
NSString *rowValue = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

ok, well the nsmanaged object is this and sets a uitableview cell to its string

```
NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.textLabel.text = [[object valueForKey:@"number"] description];
```

The reason it's showing what it does is because, as you can see, I am getting it's description. I can't find a property that would return the text value, so does anyone know how? Thanks.

Comment: You have to obtain the actual `UITextField` and use its `text` property.

Comment: I don't know. There's very little information in here.

Comment: @H2CO3 I edited it. Does what I put help?

Comment: Yes, thanks, but I believe Levi has already had the answer. How about `entity.textField.text` or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the error already occurs when you *store* a value in the managed object. Perhaps you do something like

```
[myObject setValue:[aTextField description] forKey:@"number"]
```

instead of storing the text field's text contents:

```
[myObject setValue:[aTextField text] forKey:@"number"]
```

**UPDATE:** As you write in a comment, the managed object values are stored as

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ : %@", self.numtext, self.comtext];
[newManagedObject setValue:string forKey:@"number"];
```

But the `%@` format for a `UITextField` *itself* is expanded to the text fields *description*, not the *text contents*. Therefore the `string` already looks like

```
"<UITextField: 0x1d8b7cc0; frame = (159 183; 161 30); text = 'test'; .... "
```

and this string is stored as "number" attribute in the managed object. You should use the following code instead:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ : %@", self.numtext.text, self.comtext.text];
[newManagedObject setValue:string forKey:@"number"];
```

Note that you have to delete the old database when testing this to get rid of the already existing wrong entries.

Comment: I add it like this `NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ : %@", self.numtext, self.comtext];

    [newManagedObject setValue:string forKey:@"number"];'

Comment: If `self.numtext`, `self.comtext` are `UITextField` variables, then you have to use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ : %@", self.numtext.text, self.comtext.text]`.

Comment: That did help me, I just notice what I did wrong there, but it still won't show the string.

Comment: So what is the value of `object` now?

Comment: same as before, but it saves the text, not null

Comment: So what is wrong now? - Does `[object valueForKey:@"number"]` have the correct value?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24245/discussion-between-martin-r-and-chris-loonam)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str = managedObject.objectID.URIRepresentation.absoluteString
```

Answer (score -1):

You should write:

```
Entity *entity = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *rowValue = entity.text;
```

**Edit:**

ok, then try `object.number.text;`

Comment: entity doesn't have a text property

Comment: I tried `object.number` (number is a string already) but still not working